# Error LNK2005 when trying to link against Boost 1.53

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, lnk2005

I am currently trying to link against the boost lib

```
libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib
```

which is created out of this command line

```
b2^
 --stagedir=%BOOST_OUTPUT_DIR%^
 --build-dir=%BOOST_BUILD_DIR%^
 toolset=msvc-9.0^
 link=static^
 variant=release,debug^
 threading=multi^
 runtime-link=shared^
 stage
```

but i get the following linkage error (one among many other) :

```
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) déjà défini(e) dans TrailerContest.Reflection.obj
```

I have increased the linker verbosity to know more about this error and here is what I get :

```
Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\msvcprtd.lib :
1>      "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) found
1>        Referenced in libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib(greg_month.obj)
1>        Referenced in libboost_random-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib(random_device.obj)
1>        Referenced in libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib(thread.obj)
1>        Referenced in libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib(instances.obj)
1>        Referenced in libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib(regex.obj)
1>        Referenced in libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib(w32_regex_traits.obj)
1>        Referenced in libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib(error_code.obj)
1>        Loaded msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in TrailerContest.Reflection.obj
```

it seems that all boost libs try to import std::string functions from MSVCP90D.dll

```
__imp_??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ
```

while my own program seems to embed the std::string code and therefore tries to link internally.

```
      ??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ
```

I think I have two choices here, either I make boost embed std::string code so boost and my program have the same declaration in both objs and linkage can be achieved.
Either my program must import std::string code from MSVCP90D.dll the same way boost does.

The problem is I don't know how to ask boost to compile without importing std::string code.
And I don't know how to force my program to import std::string from MSVCP90D.dll, anyone has an idea ?

I must say that my program is obviously compiled with /MDd option. Boost should also be compiled with this option with the line **runtime-link=shared**